# Error in optim function while using FinAsym package

Tags: r, runtime-error, mathematical-optimization

I want to estimate PIN using FinAsym packagage. I have two datasets and both are same in structure and class.
This one works fine:

```
dput(ms)
structure(c(4, 5, 4), .Dim = c(3L, 1L))
par0 <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
param_optim <- optim(par0, pin_likelihood, gr=NULL, ms)
alph <- c( param_optim$par[3] )
miu <- c( param_optim$par[2] )
delt <- c( param_optim$par[4] )
epsi <- c( param_optim$par[1] )
PSI <- c( ( 1-miu )*epsi + miu )
pin <- c( miu/PSI )
```

and gives the required output

```
dput(pin)
5.85127760950505e-07
```

But this one does not work

```
dput(m2)
structure(c(580, 2163, 2185), .Dim = c(3L, 1L))
par0 <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
param_optim <- optim(par0, pin_likelihood, gr=NULL, m2)
alph <- c( param_optim$par[3] )
miu <- c( param_optim$par[2] )
delt <- c( param_optim$par[4] )
epsi <- c( param_optim$par[1] )
PSI <- c( ( 1-miu )*epsi + miu )
pin <- c( miu/PSI )
```

And gives the follwoing error:

```
Error in optim(par0, pin_likelihood, gr = NULL, m2) : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters
```

I am very confused as both are same in structure and class then why I am getting this error? Any help is appreciated.